# different layout&font-size in different browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```css
.header{
 z-index:3;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:10%;
 top:0px;
 background-color: white;
}

.header .header-bg {
 background-color: rgba(248,221,225,0.7);
 display:table;
 margin:auto;
 height:30px;
 width:30%;
}

.header .title-center{
 text-decoration: underline;
 position:absolute;
 margin:0;
 left:50%;
 top:60%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

 <div class="header"> 
  <div class="header-bg"> </div>
  <div class="title-center">header</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I developed a web page, I tested it using Chrome. After finishing, I tested it with firefox/IE/Edge, and found the font-size are much smaller than it used to be in Chrome. When I checked the debug tool on Firefox, it seemed that the size of the same div is not the same for firefox and chrome. Actually, the difference is great.

More wierd, when I click into a modal in chrome, and refresh the window, the path changed to index.html#, then, the layout and div size is almost the same as the other browsers.

Anyone has idea why this happened? and How to deal with it? Thanks in advance!!

The following is part of my code for header.

Comment: This is usually caused by not reseting your css, and not setting a starting font size for your entire document.     http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Comment: Sounds like you just have changed the zoom level in one of your browsers.

Comment: Er...it do have something with the zoom level. And the zoom level seems only work for my web page since other page on Chrome is at 100% zoom level. I have reset the css as well. Thanks a lot for everyone's help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add any default font-family in your css after that you can see same fonts on all browser

and add reset css from http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ in header section!

Comment: thanks. Can you give me an exampel on setting the default font-family? I guess it should be in html{}? How about the case I want to have other font in different part?

Comment: Yes Sure, Please have a look  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

Answer (score 1):

a) Each browser will have their own default font size predefined.

1) For chrome : Setting > Show Advanced setting > Web Content > Font size

2) For Firefox : Tools > Options > Content > Fonts & Color

Whenever the CSS doesn't have font size mentioned in their styles, browser will use their predefined default font size. Better define font-size in your CSS.

b) index.html# issue
Whenever you click on any clickable elements usually anchor hyperlink, browser tries to navigate to that page or section where the href="" if pointing. When a hyperlink doesn't have href="" we'll get "#" as a dummy pointer. Example

```
<a href="#">Test link</a> or <a href="index.html"> Test link</a>
```

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0):

Each web browser has different defaults for font so you want to reset you CSS before adding your custom style.

Have a read of http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be initial values of some elements that differ through browers. The easiest and most reliable way to solve it would be using something like [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).